# Need to build a grok pattern out of string

Tags: grok

I am having a difficult time turning this into a grok regex pattern that I can use for logstash, etc

2022-05-18 11:47:32,824 [vm3p-gen-hst-app006][45545][sts-assis-post-string-communication_applications-instances-id-sessions:{60000}:3,0,0][209,151,281,628][0,0,0,0,3]

Can someone perhaps help me figure it out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have constructed the grok pattern for the above mentioned input. Please try and keep posted.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time_stamp},%{DATA:byte} \[%{DATA:username}\]\[%{DATA:num_bytes}\]\[%{DATA:session}:\{%{DATA:bytes}\}:%{DATA:lat}\]\[%{DATA:ip_add}\]\[%{DATA:load}\]
```

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ --> Used this site for constructing grok pattern

**Output:**
[image: grok output]

Keep Posted !!! Thanks !!!